# zipfile.Zipfile open specific file within a Zip folder

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to build a program that downloads and extracts zip files from various websites.  I've pasted the two programs I've written to do this.  The first program is a "child" program names "urls", which I import to the second program.  I'm trying to iterate through each of the urls, and within each url iterate through each data file, and finally check if the "keywords" list is a part of the file name, and if yes, download and extract that file.  I'm getting stuck on the part where I need to loop through the list of "keywords" to check against the file names I want to download.  Would you be able to help?  I appreciate any of your suggestions or guidance.  Thank you.  Andy

```
**Program #1 called "urls":**

urls = [
    "https://www.dentoncad.com/content/data-extracts/1-appraisal-data-extracts/1-2019/1-preliminary/2019-preliminary" \
    "-protax-data.zip",
    "http://www.dallascad.org/ViewPDFs.aspx?type=3&id=//DCAD.ORG\WEB\WEBDATA\WEBFORMS\DATA%20PRODUCTS\DCAD2020_" \
    "CURRENT.ZIP"
]

keywords = [
    "APPRAISAL_ENTITY_INFO",
    "SalesExport",
    "account_info",
    "account_apprl_year",
    "res_detail",
    "applied_std_exempt",
    "land",
    "acct_exempt_value"
]`enter code here`

    enter code here

**Program #2 (primary program):**

import requests
import zipfile
import os
import urls


def main():
    print_header()
    dwnld_zfiles_from_web()


def print_header():
    print('---------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('               DOWNLOAD ZIP FILES FROM THE WEB APP')
    print('---------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print()


def dwnld_zfiles_from_web():
    file_num = 0

    dest_folder = "C:/Users/agbpi/OneDrive/Desktop/test//"

    # loop through each url within the url list, assigning it a unique file number each iteration
    for url in urls.urls:
        file_num = file_num + 1
        url_resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=5)

        if url_resp.status_code == 200:
            saved_archive = os.path.basename(url)
            with open(saved_archive, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(url_resp.content)

                # for match in urls.keywords:

                print("Extracting...", url_resp.url)

                with zipfile.ZipFile('file{0}'.format(str(file_num)), "r") as z:
                    zip_files = z.namelist()
                    # print(zip_files)
                    for content in zip_files:
                        while urls.keywords in content:
                            z.extract(path=dest_folder, member=content)
                    # while urls.keywords in zip_files:
                    #     for content in zip_files:
                    #         z.extract(path=dest_folder, member=content)

                print("Finished!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you stuck with finding a zip file or extracting a single file from a zip? What is your code so far?

Comment: @Trapli thanks for replying. here's the bit of code I'm stuck on.

Comment: @Trapli             elif "data-real-and-mh" in url_resp.url:
         with zipfile.ZipFile('file{0}'.format(str(file_num)), "r") as z:
      zip_files=print(z.namelist())  # display available files in zip folder
          if "APPRAISAL_ENTITY_INFO" in zip_files:
       z.extract(path=dest_folder, member="2019-04-04_005519_APPRAISAL_ENTITY_INFO.txt")

Comment: Sorry for the un-formatted code... I'm new to how the site works.  And I appreciate your help.  I'm trying to determine the best way to dynamically point to member="YYYY-MM-DD_APPRAISAL_ENTITY_INFO.txt" since the file name will change with date changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, updated answer based on updated question.

Your code is fine until this part:

```py
                with zipfile.ZipFile('file{0}'.format(str(file_num)), "r") as z:
                    zip_files = z.namelist()
                    # print(zip_files)
                    for content in zip_files:
                        while urls.keywords in content:
                            z.extract(path=dest_folder, member=content)
```

**Issue 1**

You already have the zip file name as `saved_archive`, but you try to open something else as a zipfile. Why `'file{0}'.format(str(file_num))`? You should just `with zipfile.ZipFile(saved_archive, "r") as z:`

**Issue 2**

`while` is kind of an `if` statement, but it does not work as a filter (it seems you wanted that). What `while` does is that it checks if the condition of the statement (after the while part) is `True`-ish and if so, it executes the indented code. And as soon as the first `False`-ish evaluation kicks in, the code execution moves on. So if your condition evaluation would yield these results `[True, False, True]`, the first would trigger the indented code to run, the second would result an exit, and the third one would be ignored due the previous exit condition. But the condition is invalid which leads to:

**Issue 3**

`url.keywords` is a `list` and `content` is a `str`. A list in string will never make sense. It is like `['apple', 'banana'] in 'b'`. `'b'` won't have such members. You could reverse the logic, but keep in mind that `'b' in ['apple', 'banana']` will be `False`, `'banana' in ['apple', 'banana']` will be `True`.

Which means in your case that this condition: `'_SalesExport.txt' in urls.keywords` will be `False`! Why? Because `url.keywords` is:

```
[
    "APPRAISAL_ENTITY_INFO",
    "SalesExport",
    "account_info",
    "account_apprl_year",
    "res_detail",
    "applied_std_exempt",
    "land",
    "acct_exempt_value"
]
```

and `SalesExport` is *not* `_SalesExport.txt`.

To achieve partial match check, you need to compare list items (strings) against a string. `"SalesExport" in "_SalesExport.txt"` is `True`, but `"SalesExport" in ["_SalesExport.txt"]` is `False` because `SalesExport` is not a member of the list.

There are three things you could do:

1. update your `keywords` list to exact filenames so `content in kw_list` could work (this means that if there is a directory structure in the zip file, you must include that one too)

```
                    for content in zip_files:
                        if content in urls.keywords:
                            z.extract(path=dest_folder, member=content)
```

2. implement a for cycle in for cycle

```
                    for content in zip_files:
                        for kw in urls.keywords:
                            if kw in content:
                                z.extract(path=dest_folder, member=content)
```

3. use a generator

```
matches = [x for x in zip_files if any(y for y in urls.keywords if y in x)]
for m in matches:
    z.extract(path=dest_folder, member=m)
```

---

Finally, a recommendation:

**Timeouts**

Be careful with

`url_resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=5)`.

"timeout" controls two things, connection timeout and read timeout. Since response may take longer than 5 sec, you may want a longer read timeout. You can specify timeout as tuple: (connect timeout, read timeout). So a better parameter would be:

`url_resp = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=(5, 120))`

Comment: thank you so much for the guidance!  I'm working through the script and will let you know how it turns out - thanks again!!!

Comment: Thank you for your help.  As update, I've tried this newly added code to the program:                 with zipfile.ZipFile('file{0}'.format(str(file_num)), "r") as z:
                    zip_files = z.namelist()
                    # print(zip_files)
                    for content in zip_files:
                        while urls.keywords in content:
                            z.extract(path=dest_folder, member=content)

Comment: However, I'm receiving this error:    while urls.keywords in content:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: I've created this list from "urls.keywords"  keywords = [
    "APPRAISAL_ENTITY_INFO",
    "SalesExport",
    "account_info",
    "account_apprl_year",
    "res_detail",
    "applied_std_exempt",
    "land",
    "acct_exempt_value"
]

Comment: And I'm hoping to be able to iterate through the key word list extracting only the content that matches the list.  Do you have any suggestions on how I could do this?

Comment: Hi @Andy, as the error message states, you seem trying to use a list as filename. Wihtout seeing your code as is, it is hard to tell where and what went wrong. Update your question with your current code or open a new question with your actual code, or copy your code to https://pastebin.com/ and add here in comment how your code looks now.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I'll update my question with my current code.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.  I've made the changes you've suggested and they really have helped, thank you!  I've posted my updated code.  Would you be able to suggest how I could loop through the "keywords" list to check if those key words exist in the file names I'm attempting to download and then extract only those files which contain the "keywords" from within the urls?

Comment: thank you!  I will check out your feedback.  I really appreciate your help.